# Spring property editor doesn't work

Tags: spring-mvc

I've come to spring from jsf, and I'm new in this,,, I want to have a converter for my IdField class,,, I did some research and wrote my own property editor,,,

```
public class IdFieldPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
```

and I registered it in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
            <entry key="com.example.IdField">
                <bean class="com.example.IdFieldPropertyEditor" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

so , as I understood these steps are enough, but I still get an error like cannon convert from String to IdField,,,

can anyone help to understand what steps I missed? Thanks,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CustomEditorConfigurer` has nothing to do with Spring MVC, it configures property editors for interpreting values in XML config files.

To configure property editors for specific controller, use `@InitBinder`-annotated method. To do it globally for all controllers, use custom `WebBindingInitializer`. See [15.3.2.12 Customizing WebDataBinder initialization](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder).

Comment: Or advise controllers with the @ControllerAdvice annotation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice